# Understanding stack overflow handling in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow

I was curious about how to catch stack overflows in C and stumble across the [GNU libsigseg library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libsigsegv/).

This library can catch stack overflows on a lot of platforms and provides an [implementation example](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=libsigsegv.git;a=blob;f=tests/stackoverflow1.c;h=b5c80f22fccb6536e300ed171b58e264f8397bb8;hb=8a99261f548bbdffc3a8847f79557277aed064a6).
In order to install a stack overflow listener with this library, one must first reserve some space for an alternate stack.
From what I understood, this alternate stack is used to run the listener because the real stack is unusable.

The alternate stack is reserved in [altstack.h](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=libsigsegv.git;a=blob;f=tests/altstack.h;h=bba4818332c1ad0c0a66e6d92e6c92c9875cb7c7;hb=8a99261f548bbdffc3a8847f79557277aed064a6) (line 40), and looks like this:

```
[][      ][             ][      ]
|    |           |          |
|    |           |          crumple_zone (8 KiB)
|    |           usable_space (16 KiB)
|    crumple_zone (8 KiB)
offset (31 B)
```

The usable space is what is actually used and the crumple zones are here to prevent an overflow on the alternate stack: If it overflows, it does it into allocated space, preventing a segfault, and one might have time to detect it.

But,

1. I don't understand why there is a crumple zone before AND after the stack; The stack grows in only one direction. Is it because some platforms have stack that grows in one direction, and other platforms in the other direction?
2. I don't understand why there is an offset.

Here is the explanation given by the author:

> glibc says: Users should use SIGSTKSZ as the size of user-supplied buffers.
> We want to detect stack overflow of the alternate stack in a nicer manner than just crashing, so we overallocate in comparison to what we hand libsigsegv.
> Also, we intentionally hand an unaligned pointer, to ensure the alternate stack still ends up aligned.

The last statement lost me a bit: "... we intentionally hand an unaligned pointer, to ensure the alternate stack still ends up aligned".
How can the stack ends up aligned if we make so it's unaligned?

Comment: Read about `-fsanitize=address`. `can catch stack overflows on a lot of platform` I see the library catches "page faults". It's not only stackoverflow.

Comment: @KamilCuk This library can be used to catch ONLY stack overflows, also `-fsanitize=address` comes with a non-negligible slowdown. source: https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerPerformanceNumbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand why there is a crumple zone before AND after the stack;

The stack is declared as a global `char mystack_storage[...]`.
Assuming that stack grows down, you need the crumple zone at the low end of storage to detect overflow of the alternate stack itself.

Question: what *follows* the `mystack_storage[]` array?
Answer: you don't know.

What if there is another array immediately after, and what if *that* array is written out of bounds (e.g. with something like `other_array[-20] = 'a';`)?

To detect such underflow, you need the crumple zone on the other end as well.

> How can the stack ends up aligned if we make so it's unaligned?

The `mystack` pointer is intentionally misaligned. If it was used directly as the alternate stack, it would violate stack alignment requirements on many platforms, and would most likely cause a crash.

To prevent this, the library must not be using `mystack` directly, but *aligning* it somewhere else.

The code you pointed to is intended to *test* that the *other* code is working properly.

**Update:**

> I still don't understand the offset. Why the mystack pointer would violate stack alignment requirement if used without offset?

Without offset, `mystack`'s alignment is unknown. It may *happen* to be aligned on 16-byte, 8-byte, or even 1-byte boundary.

With the offset, it is *guaranteed* to be misaligned (aligned on 1-byte boundary).

> Why it isn't the other way around: by adding the offset it's intentionally misaligned and violate stack alignment requirement.

Yes, the pointer is *intentionally* misaligned.

The point was: the code which actually *uses* `mystack` (that code is elsewhere, I didn't look for it), is already prepared for dealing with misaligned `mystack`, by properly aligning it (let's call that "alignment code"). And the code you pointed to is intended to *exercise* that other "alignment code".

Now, *where* is that "alignment code"?

I thought it's somewhere else in the library, but I was **wrong**. The misaligned `mystack` pointer is used *directly* [here](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=libsigsegv.git;a=blob;f=src/handler-unix.c;h=8089ff455637791ab148b509ddc88ac51df6e5ae;hb=HEAD#l548).

So who is doing the required alignment then? The kernel does!

From `man sigaltstack`:

```
 ss.ss_sp
    This field specifies the starting address of the stack.  When a signal
    handler is invoked on the alternate stack, the kernel automatically
    aligns the address given in ss.ss_sp to a suitable address boundary
    for the underlying hardware architecture.
```

So the "other code" that the misalignment of `mystack` is intended to exercise is not in the library, it's in the kernel.

Comment: And I always thought crumple-zones were crash-worthiness issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still don't understand the offset. Why the `mystack` pointer would violate stack alignment requirement if used without offset? Why it isn't the other way around: by adding the offset it's intentionally misaligned and violate stack alignment requirement.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! I understand it now.